# Format brace-list of lambda expressions nicely

Tags: c++, lambda, code-formatting, clang-format

Is there any way I can setup clang-format to nicely* format an expression like this?

```cpp
foo({
    [](int) {
        bar();
        baz();
    },
    [](float) {}
});
```

With my current config this gets smushed into this abomination:

```cpp
foo({ [](int) {
         bar();
         baz();
     },
      [](float) {} });
```

Here `foo` is a function template that takes a `std::tuple` of generic types as an argument.

I have many function calls like this over my code base and I have to wrap them all into `// clang-format off` `// clang-format on` comments which is really annoying.

*And by nicely I mean like in the first example. Correct indentation for nested braces.

Here is my current config file:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveMacros: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: None
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: Consecutive
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: None
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
AttributeMacros: ['__capability']
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: MultiLine
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
QualifierAlignment: Right
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
BasedOnStyle:    ''
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: OuterScope
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 10
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 300
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 100
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PointerAlignment: Left
PPIndentWidth:   -1
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: false
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros:   true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard:        Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        4
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
...
```

Comment: Great, but I don't get the same result as you do from that. I get [this](https://pastebin.com/xXet07TF) with clang-format 17.0.6.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, seems like I should update, I'm still on version 16. But nonetheless it's still not what I would expect (although it is an improvement).